# Pampers tzovehah (dyeing) on shabbas

Tags: halacha, shabbat, bathroom, color, baby-infant

Pampers make diapers which have a wetness indicator. Initially it is a yellow stripe when dry; when wet it turns blue. I am wondering whether this would be considered tzoveha.

http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/aplus/detail-page/B00DFFT8AU_pampers_201306244_4627_lg.jpg

Comment: Seems like that dying is incidental to its use, and not the purpose of the diaper... unless you plan to make pediatric urinary art.

Comment: i had this question yesterday as well!

Answer (score 5):

[The Star-K's Rabbi Frankel discusses it.](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-InsightsFromTheInstitute-Spring10.htm)

> Rav Heinemann shlit”a suggests that there is further reason to be lenient in the case of the diaper with a color-changing stripe.  Rav Moshe Feinstein zt”l states that, on Shabbos, one is allowed to wear photo-gray glasses which darken when exposed to sulight, even though walking outside will cause the lens to change color. ... Similarly, any color change which results from diapering a baby would not be classified as tvziah, as this is not the derech of the melacha.  If so, it could be argued that even a person who desires the color change feature would be permitted to use the diaper on Shabbos.
>
> Nevertheless, Rav Heinemann paskens that someone should preferably not use such a diaper on Shabbos if it was bought particularly because of its color changing feature.   He may, however, use such a diaper if this particular feature is insignificant to him.

Comment: Interesting. In [Kashrus Kurrents - Nov 2009](http://www.star-k.com/kyk2009-11_November.pdf) the Star-K says it should not be used. Did they change their mind?

Comment: Yes they did change their mind per [Matzav.com](http://matzav.com/shabbos-alert-regarding-pampers).

Answer (score 0):

Rav Shmuel Kamenetsky (Kovetz Halachos, Shabbos 2: Page 870) writes that the use of such diapers are permitted.